# Identification of control column spade

Tags: aviation-history, feature-identification

I have a control column head similar to that used on the Spitfire and Hurricane but with two levers for cables coming up from the stick. I would like to find out what aircraft used this type.

Markings on the side  are 444/35,  AK-2 and AK-8 in an oval and A1D 4 in a partially stamped circle.

Comment: Could you post a photo?

Comment: D. H. Mosquito?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! A photo would be *very* helpful here.

Comment: The bomber Mosquito had a W wheel, and the fighter version had kind of an L shaped extension of the column, similar to a Spit's spade control, but with a pistol grip.